# How to make a particular function work for certain rows only based on the column value in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, logic

I have doubt about the query for making output like this.

The query should produce a table if the invoice date is not existing in sample database and also having two posting dates then it should display a single row with earliest posting date (having same invoice number) eg :china

if the invoice date is existing in a sample database and having two posting dates then it should display all the rows with same invoice number with no change eg: london, australia

Other rows which have single posting date ( whether they exist or not existing in a sample database) they should display their row. eg:India

Existing Example table:

| INVOICE NUMBER | NAME | Invoice Date | Posting date | Place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2050 | Dinosaur | 20.03.1999 | 20.05.1998 | London |
| 2050 | Dinosaur | 20.03.1999 | 25.04.1995 | Australia |
| 2045 | Birds | 26.06.2005 | 18.03.1997 | America |
| 2045 | Birds | 26.06.2005 | 27.07.1995 | China |
| 2075 | Lion | 22.04.2012 | 12.06.2012 | India |

I want to query as single Query to display output like this:

| INVOICE NUMBER | NAME | Invoice Date | Posting date | Place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2050 | Dinosaur | 20.03.1999 | 20.05.1998 | London |
| 2050 | Dinosaur | 20.03.1999 | 25.04.1995 | Australia |
| 2045 | Birds | 26.06.2005 | 27.07.1995 | China |
| 2075 | Lion | 22.04.2012 | 12.06.2012 | India |

I'm not able to that as a single SELECT query and I also checked with particular date instead of checking in database, it too failed. Please help me on this.

Remark : this is sample table, it will be filled with dynamic values with dynamic columns from codebase, so, ommiting American row is my not expected output, getting output based on the logic is the expected output.

Thank you

Comment: Isn't it basic sql aggregation?

Comment: I don't follow. Your sample data and expected results are the same other than that the row with `'America'` is omitted. To get from your sample to your expected, you would just do `WHERE Place != 'America'`

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _if the invoice date is not existing in sample database_. There is an invoice date in your first two rows. Or do you mean there is a second table with dates in them?

Comment: What's different between the pairs  London and Australia,  vs  China and America.  In both case the two rows have the same Invoice Number, same Name, same Invoice Date, and different Posting Dates.   Why are they being treated differently.

Comment: Due to business logic, to tell you in detail they want this change(i.e selecting row with earliest posting date) to be applied on newly created invoices only not on old invoices so, i am filtering out them based on their invoice date.

Comment: OK so please explain the logic. What date do you want to start calculating this?